# Multiplicacion de Matrices en C

Tags: c

Hola tengo un Problema con la multiplicacion de matrices, cuando quiero multiplicar una 2x2 por una 2x10, me arroja valores incorrectos. Agradezco la ayuda...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// constantes que se aplican a matrices 2 x 2

const int ROW2=2;
const int COLUMNS2=2;

// constantes que se aplican a matrices 2 x 10

const int COLUMNAS10=10;

void multiplicaciondematrices (int matriz [ROW2][COLUMNS2], int matrizx10 [ROW2][COLUMNAS10], int matrixfinal[ROW2][COLUMNAS10]);// Prototipo de multiplicar una matriz 2 x 2 por una 2 x 10
void cargamatriz2x10 (int matrixrecargada [ROW2][COLUMNAS10] ); // prototipo que carga la matrix 2 x 10
void muestramatriz2x10 ( int mmatrixrecargada [ROW2] [COLUMNAS10]); // prototipo de la funcion que muestra la matriz 2 x 10
void cargamatriz2x2 (int matriz [ROW2][COLUMNS2] );// Prototipo que carga la matrix 2x2


int main()
{

    // Se declaran las variables que se van a usar en la funcion que multiplica la matriz 2 x 2 por una 2 x 10

    int matrizfinal [ROW2][COLUMNAS10];
    int matrizx10 [ROW2][COLUMNAS10];
    int matriz[ROW2][COLUMNS2];

    // Llamado a las funciones de carga de matrices

    printf(" Cargue una matriz de 2 x 2 \n\n");
    cargamatriz2x2(matriz);
    printf(" Cargue una matriz de 2 x 10\n\n");
    cargamatriz2x10(matrizx10);

    multiplicaciondematrices(matriz, matrizx10,matrizfinal);
    muestramatriz2x10(matrizfinal);


    return 0;
}


// Funcion que carga una matriz de 2 x 2

void cargamatriz2x2 (int matriz [ROW2][COLUMNS2] )
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    system("cls");
    for (i=0; i<ROW2; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<COLUMNS2; j++)
        {
            printf("Ingres un Valor Entero en la posicion fila(%d): columna(%d): ",i,j);
            scanf(" %d",&matriz [i][j]);
        }
    }
}

// Funcion que carga una matriz 2 x 10
void cargamatriz2x10 (int matrizx10 [ROW2][COLUMNAS10] )
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    system("cls");
    for (i=0; i<ROW2; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<COLUMNAS10; j++)
        {
            printf("Ingres un Valor Entero en la posicion fila(%d): columna(%d): ",i,j);

            scanf(" %d",&matrizx10 [i][j]);
        }
    }
}

// Funcion que multiplica una matriz 2x2 por una 2 x 10

void multiplicaciondematrices (int matriz [ROW2][COLUMNS2], int matrizx10 [ROW2][COLUMNAS10], int matrizfinal[ROW2][COLUMNAS10])
{
    int i=0;
    int u=0;
    int k=0;

    for(i=0; i<ROW2; i++)
    {
      for(u=0; u<COLUMNS2; u++)
        {
            matrizfinal[i][k]=0;
            for(k=0; k<COLUMNAS10; k++)
            {
                matrizfinal[i][k]+=(matriz[i][u]*matrizx10[u][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Funcion que muestra una matriz 2 x 10

void muestramatriz2x10 ( int matriz [ROW2] [COLUMNAS10])
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    system("cls");


    for (i=0; i<ROW2; i++)
    {
        printf("\n \n \t");
        for (j=0; j<COLUMNAS10; j++)
        {
            if (matriz [i][j]<9)
            {
                printf(" ");
                printf(" %d ",matriz[i][j]);

            }
            else
            {
                printf(" %d ",matriz[i][j]);
            }

        }
        printf("\n \n");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error parece estar en la función `multiplicaciondematrices`, concretamente
en el ciclo `for` que itera con la variable u en la línea que inicializas `matriz final[i][k]`.

```
for(u=0; u<COLUMNS2; u++)
{
  matrizfinal[i][k]=0; // Aquí
  for(k=0; k<COLUMNAS10; k++)
  {
    matrizfinal[i][k]+=(matriz[i][u]*matrizx10[u][k]);
  }
}
```

En la primera iteración del ciclo la variable k está inicializada a 0. Sin embargo en la siguiente iteración, k tiene el valor que la hizo salir del for interno, es decir 10. Por lo tanto la linea mencionada es igual a

```
matrizfinal[i][10] = 0;
```

Lo cual es un acceso fuera del rango de la matriz (el máximo es 9) mientras que dejas sin inicializar la casilla que realmente pretendías. Como estas dejando basura en la matriz final los resultados son erróneos.

Una posible reestructuración de tus ciclos que corregiría tu problema es la siguiente:

```
    for(int u=0; u < COLUMNAS10; u++)
    {
        matrizfinal[i][u] = 0;

        for(int k=0; k < ROW2; k++)
        {
            matrizfinal[i][u] += (matriz[i][k]*matrizx10[k][u]);
        }
    }
```